# Which Statement will decide the termination of while loop in the given code?

Tags: arrays, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
while(1)
{
  k = j + d;
  if (k >= n)
    k = k - n;
  if (k == i)
    break;
  arr[j] = arr[k];
  j = k;
}
```

I was going through "Juggling Algorithm" for Array Rotation and saw this piece of code there. Now i am confusing about which statement of code will terminate while loop.Is while(1) here making condition true for ever ?

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And tell us which language the program is in (using the correct tags).

Answer (score 0):

It will will run forever unless it hits the `break` statement - which will exit the loop and in this case this happens when `(k == i)`

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/jump-statements)